# Backbonejs - router initializing function calls 3 times - on navigation change

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

In my app, I have main link and sub links, so each of the link change, i am calling the appropriate function.

so, each time the router change, i need to call my navigation function do this, i did like this:

```
var appRouters = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            "general/":"defaultRoute",
            "general/:page/":"generalSublinks",
            "repositories/":"repositories",
            "repositories/:page/":"repositoriesSublinks",
            "savedSearch/":"savedSearch",
            "favourites/":"favourites",
            "reports/":"reports",
            "preferences/":"preferences",
            "preferences/:page/":"preferencesSubLinks",
            '*path':  'defaultRoute'
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.bind("all", this.navigationUpdate); // calling 3 times each navigation change.. how to solve this?
        },
        navigationUpdate:function(){
            new naviView();
        },
        defaultRoute:function(){
            new dBView();
        },
        generalSublinks:function(id){
            if(id === "dashBoard"){
                this.defaultRoute();
            }else if(id === "myTask"){
                new myTaskView();
            }else if (id === "myDocument"){
                new myDocView();
            }else if (id === "myTemplate"){
                new myTempView();
            }else if (id === "search"){
                new mySearchView();
            }
        }
```

});

it works fine. But i am getting the `navigationUpdate`  - called as 3 times. any idea to solve this pelase..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are listening to `all`.

Try adding this to see what events you are picking up:

```
    navigationUpdate:function(eventName){
         console.log(eventName);
         new naviView();
    }
```

To fix it, you should be able to do this:

```
this.on("route", this.navigationUpdate, this);
```

Comment: I did this, My bad i am getting the console 2 times!

Comment: on load the app, using the navigation as  Nothing("") or ("#") or ("#/") - i would like to call default function

Comment: try adding an argument to defaultRoute, like this: defaultRoute(path)

Comment: Yes, really helpful. I agree your answer.